# How to return a numpy array as an image using FastAPI?

Tags: python, numpy, fastapi, python-imageio

I load an image with `img = imageio.imread('hello.jpg')`.
I want to return this numpy array as an image. I know I can do `return FileResponse('hello.jpg')`, however, in the future, I will have the pictures as numpy arrays.

How can I return the numpy array `img` from FastAPI server in a way that it is equivalent to `return FileResponse('hello.jpg')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using [`StreamingResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse), as suggested by some other answer. If the entire image bytes are loaded into memory from the beginning (e.g., into an in-memory bytes buffer), using `StreamingResponse` makes little sense. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804) for more details. You should instead use [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response) and pass the image bytes, after converting the numpy array into a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) buffered stream, as described in the [documentation](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#writing-to-bytesio) of the [`Imageio`](https://github.com/imageio/imageio) library that you are using—if you instead wish to use `PIL` or [`Pillow`](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) library (the successor of `PIL`, which added Python 3.x support), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804). You can also define the [`media_type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types), as well as set the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894771/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804), so that the image is viewed in the browser (if you would like to have the image downloaded rather than viewed in the browser, then use `attachment` insetad of `inline`, as described in the linked answers above). Example below:

```py
import io
import imageio
from imageio import v3 as iio
from fastapi import Response

@app.get("/image", response_class=Response)
def get_image():
    im = imageio.imread("test.jpeg") # 'im' could be an in-memory image (numpy array) instead
    with io.BytesIO() as buf:
        iio.imwrite(buf, im, plugin="pillow", format="JPEG")
        im_bytes = buf.getvalue()
        
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="test.jpeg"'}
    return Response(im_bytes, headers=headers, media_type='image/jpeg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StreamingResponse (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#using-streamingresponse-with-file-like-objects) to do it e.g., but before you will need to convert your numpy array to the `io.BytesIO` or `io.StringIO`