# Passing image to python FastAPI api endpoint

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I'm quite new to apis and i have a problem. I want to use it to pass an image and process it. I thought just changing it to base64 will help and i will just pass a string to endpoint. But problem is that in base64 string there are '/' signs which break my url. Any ideas how i can fix it or there are any better ideas out there?

Code is simple:

```
app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/get_predictions/{base64_str}")
def get_predictions(base64_str: str):
    return get_model_predictions(base64_str)
```

get_model_predictions just handles the image and return what it has to return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use UploadFile to pass files to your endpoint.

Here is an example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile

@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

Be careful in my example I use the POST method and not GET.
I allow myself to offer you a solution with POST since you say you want to 'pass' an image, so this is done with a POST route and not GET

You can learn more by looking at this section of the documentation:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/

Answer (score 1):

Using get request for file transfer is a bad idea. Firstly you will have a giant url, secondly information you pass in get request may be exposed to other people.

The right solution is to use **post** request that will hide all the information in the request body. There you can transfer your images not only by using base_64 but also like multipart-formdata.

Here is the documentation to the Fast API post requests: [post request](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/) or [answer how to post an image using Fast API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178227/fast-api-how-to-show-an-image-from-post-in-get)