# How to render Streamable image on React coming from FastAPI server?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, image, fastapi

I would like to render an image on React returned from FastAPI backend using `StreamingResponse`. The image is in the form of a `numpy` array, which is of `cv2` type of object.

```
@app.post("/predict")
async def root(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    global model
    global store_coordinates
    global store_faces
    global store_mesh

    content = await file.read()
    nparr = np.fromstring(content, np.uint8)
    bg_img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    ......................
    for i in range(len(store_coordinates)):
            x, y, w, h = store_coordinates[i]
            bg_img [b:b + d, a:a + c] = store_mesh[i]
    
    res,im_png = cv2.imencode(".png", bg_img)
    return StreamingResponse(io.BytesIO(im_png.tobytes()), media_type="image/png")
```

Here, I have created an API endpoint in which the uploaded image is received using `POST` request, and a `StreamableResponse(Image)` is returned.
How can I render this returned response on React frontend?

React Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Detect extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    content: "",
    image: null,
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  handleImageChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      image: e.target.files[0],
    });
  };

  
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
    let form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append("image", this.state.image, this.state.image.name);
    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict";
    axios
      .post(url, form_data, {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <p>
            <input
              type="file"
              id="image"
              accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
              onChange={this.handleImageChange}
              required
            />
          </p>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <div id="image-render">
          <img></img>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Detect;
```

I would like to render the returned image in the `div` tag which has the `id` of `image-render`.

**Edit** - This is the response I get from my backend.

[image]

Comment: You can set the src of the img tag to `data:image/png;base64,<base 64 encoded img data>` - either return base64 data directly from your API or convert it in Javascript by handling the response from the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options:

1. encode the image data into [Base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) format on server side and
   return the base64-encoded string, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73726553/17865804) and [this
   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73264904/17865804),
   for example:

   ```py
   base64_string= base64.b64encode(image_bytes).decode('utf-8')
   return base64_string
   ```

   which can then be used to display the image in an HTML page as shown
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html), for instance:

   ```html
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,ADD_BASE64_STRING_HERE>
   ```
2. or, send the raw bytes from the server, as you currently do. However, it
   might be best not to use a [`StreamingResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse) (as shown in the
   example you provided) for sending the raw bytes, as, in your case, the
   entire image bytes are already loaded into memory. Thus, you should rather
   use a custom [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response), as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804) and [this
   answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71643439/17865804), for example:

   ```py
   return Response(image_bytes, media_type='image/jpeg')
   ```

   On client side (using JavaScript), convert the raw bytes into either a
   base64-encoded string (using [`btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa), [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)
   and [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array)), or a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object (and then call
   [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#creating_a_url_representing_the_contents_of_a_typed_array) to create a URL representing the `Blob`
   object).

The examples below demonstrate how to implement the two methods explained in Option 2  above (i.e., having the server sending raw image bytes and, on client side, converting the image bytes to either a base64-encoded string or `Blob` object), using either [`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [`Axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) library.

## Using Fetch API

### Option 1 - Convert raw image bytes into Blob object

```js
fetch('/predict', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
    })
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
        var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
        image.onload = function(){
            URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src); // release the blob URL once the image is loaded
        }
        image.src = blobURL;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

### Option 2 - Convert raw image bytes into base64-encoded string

```js
fetch('/predict', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
    })
    .then(response => {
        contentType = response.headers.get('content-type')
        return response.arrayBuffer();
    })
    .then(arrayBuffer => {
        base64string = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)))
        var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
        image.src = "data:" + contentType + ";base64," + base64string;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

**Remember** to define an `<img>` tag in your HTML file, where you wish to display the image:

```html
<img id="myImage" src="">
```

## Using Axios

### Option 1 - Convert raw image bytes into Blob object

```js
axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/upload',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        responseType: "blob"
    })
    .then(response => {
        var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
        var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
        image.onload = function(){
            URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src); // release the blob URL once the image is loaded
        }
        image.src = blobURL;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

### Option 2 - Convert raw image bytes into base64-encoded string

```js
axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/predict',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        responseType: "arraybuffer"
    })
    .then(response => {
        base64string = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(response.data)))
        contentType = response.headers['content-type']
        return base64string;
    })
    .then(base64string => {
        var image = document.getElementById("myImage");
        image.src = "data:" + contentType + ";base64," + base64string;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

**Remember** to define an `<img>` tag in your HTML file, where you wish to display the image:

```html
<img id="myImage" src="">
```

Comment: Please look at the edit part I am getting this message in the console while implementing the solution