# How to send multiple images from FastAPI backend to JavaScript frontend using StreamingResponse?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, stream, fastapi

I have a FastAPI endpoint `/image/ocr` that accepts, processes and returns multiple images as a `StreamingResponse`:

```py
async def streamer(images):
    for image in images:
        # Bytes
        image_bytes = await image.read()

        # PIL PNG
        image_data = Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes))

        # Process
        # image_processed = ...
    
        # Convert from PIL PNG to JPEG Bytes
        image_ocr = BytesIO()

        image_ocr.save(image_processed, format='JPEG')

        yield image_ocr.getvalue()

@router.post('/ocr', summary='Process images')
async def ocr(images: List[UploadFile]):
    return StreamingResponse(
        streamer(images),
        status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        media_type='image/jpeg'
    )
```

In my React application I send multiple images to the `/image/ocr` endpoint using Axios configured to `arraybuffer`, and convert the returned images to `Base64` using `btoa`, `String.fromCharCode` and `Unit8Array`:

```js
const imageSubmit = async data => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    
    // A `useRef` that stores the uploaded images
    data?.current?.files?.successful.map(image =>
        formData.append('images', image.data)
    )

    try {
        const response = await request.post(
            '/image/ocr',
            formData,
            {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}
        )

        const base64String = btoa(
            String.fromCharCode(
                ...new Uint8Array(response.data)
            )
        )

        const contentType = response.headers['content-type']

        const fullBase64String = `data:${contentType};base64,${base64String}`

        return fullBase64String
    } catch (error) {
        // Error log
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm sending multiple images, for example, [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRD1f.png) and [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3ozM.png), that are being accepted, processed and returned by the endpoint `/image/ocr`, but when I convert the `response.data` using the method in the last code snippet I only get one `Base64` image.

I took a look at the raw `response` to see if I could iterate over the `ArrayBuffer` that I get through `response.data`:

[Array Buffer object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0qBs.png)

But it didn't work with a `for(const image of response.data) {}`. I saw that `ArrayBuffer` has a `slice` method, but I'm not sure if it means that both images are in the `ArrayBuffer` and I need to slice and then convert, which is strange since at least one image is being converted to `Base64` as of now, or convert it to another type since I saw that it can be done in some different ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71313129/how-to-render-streamable-image-on-react-coming-from-fastapi-server), [here](https://nono.ma/fetch-multiple-images-or-files-at-once-with-promises-in-typescript) and [here](https://javascript.info/blob).

> If the `slice` option is the right one I'm not sure how to select the start and end since the values in the `ArrayBuffer` are just random numbers and symbols.

Any idea on how to get both images in `Base64` on my React application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render Streamable image on React coming from FastAPI server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71313129/how-to-render-streamable-image-on-react-coming-from-fastapi-server)

Comment: No. I linked this question you sent in mine because I took a look at it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research I gave up on Axios since the [documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) says that it "makes XMLHttpRequests from the browser", meaning that it doesn't support stream.

Reading more about the [Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API) and watching a Google's series on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9PpImUEeUA), I started using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), as it supports streaming for both writing (16:26) and reading (6:24).

By replacing the `try` block in my question with this:

```js
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/image/ocr', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        Authorization: ''
    },
    body: formData
})

const reader = response.body.getReader()

while (true) {
    const { value, done } = await reader.read()

    // Base64
    const base64 = `data:${response.headers['content-type']};base64,${btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(value)))}`

    console.log(base64)

    if (done) break
}
```

I'm able to use the asynchronous generator along with the `StreamingResponse` and get multiple images in my React application.

> Its worth to dive deeper in the stream API since it can also work as a Websocket without having to write a specific back-end that deals with sockets