# Can't display a blob image coming from FastAPI in Next JS

Tags: image, next.js, blob, fastapi

So I have my own API built with FastAPI that returns an image with

```
return Response(content=img_byte_arr.getvalue(), media_type="image/jpeg")
```

Everything works fine in the FastAPI Swagger UI as I can see the image

I have then a Next JS server action that correctly fetch the API with await fetch, get the blob and pass the ObjectURL to the client component with

```
const blob = await response.blob();
const imageBase64 = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
return imageBase64
```

Now the issue is that when I try to show the image on the client I got the error `Not allowed to load local resource: blob:nodedata:3d26ac0d-f5fc-4161-a40f-2dfa21d3df1d` even in my Vercel development env

I can't find understand why

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71324775/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: nope, but found out a way to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end my solution was, on the server action pass the Blob into an `arrayBuffer` object

```
  const blob = await response.blob();
  let ab = await blob.arrayBuffer();
  let object = {
    image: Array.from(new Uint8Array(ab)),
    name: "image",
  };

  return object;
```

On the client side, I've converted the `arrayBuffer` into a binary data and then created the `imageURL`

```
const imageStringify = await requestImg(data);
const binaryData = Buffer.from(imageStringify.image);

const imageBase64 = URL.createObjectURL(
  new Blob([binaryData.buffer], { type: "image/jpeg" } /* (1) */)
);
```