# How to display a Matplotlib chart with FastAPI/ Nextjs without saving the chart locally?

Tags: python, matplotlib, next.js, charts, fastapi

I am using Nextjs frontend and FastAPI backend for a website. I have an input form for an 'ethereum address' on the frontend and using the inputted address, I am generating a matplotlib chart in the backend that displays 'ethereum balance over time'. Now, I am trying to return this chart using FastAPI so I can display it on the frontend. I do not want to save the chart locally.

Here is my relevant code so far:

Frontend/ nexjs file called 'Chart.tsx'. 'ethAddress' in the body is capturing data inputted in the input form.

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/image", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(ethAddress),
    }).then(fetchEthAddresses);
```

Backend python file that generates matplotlib chart called ethBalanceTracker.py

```
#Imports
#Logic for chart here

        plt.plot(times, balances)
        buf = BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(buf, format="png")
        buf.seek(0)

        return StreamingResponse(buf, media_type="image/png")
```

Backend python file using FastAPI called api.py

```
@app.get("/image")
async def get_images() -> dict:
    return {"data": images}

@app.post("/image")
async def add_image(ethAddress: dict) -> dict:

    test = EthBalanceTracker.get_transactions(ethAddress["ethAddress"])
    images.append(test)
```

I have tried the above code and a few other variants. I am using `StreamingResponse` because I do not want to save the chart locally. My issue is I cannot get the chart to display in `localhost:8000/images` and am getting an `'Internal Server Error'`.

Comment: Hey Chris, your answer was very helpful, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass [`buf.getvalue()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getvalue) as the `content` of your `Response`, in order to get the bytes containing the entire contents of the buffer. Additionally, you shouldn't be using `StreamingResponse`, if the entire image data are already loaded into memory (in this case, in an in-memory bytes buffer), but rather return a [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response) directly and set the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header, so that the image can be viewed in the browser, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586180/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71643439/17865804) answer. If you are using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), or Axios, to fetch the image, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71324775/17865804) on how to display the image on client side. You could also use FastAPI/Starlette's [`BackgroundTasks`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) to close the buffer after returning the response, in order to release the memory, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586180/17865804). Example:

```py
import io
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('AGG')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, BackgroundTasks

app = FastAPI()

def create_img():
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [7.50, 3.50]
    plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = True
    fig = plt.figure()  # make sure to call this, in order to create a new figure
    plt.plot([1, 2])
    img_buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(img_buf, format='png')
    plt.close(fig)
    return img_buf
    
@app.get('/')
def get_img(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    img_buf = create_img()
    background_tasks.add_task(img_buf.close)
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="out.png"'}
    return Response(img_buf.getvalue(), headers=headers, media_type='image/png')
```

If you would like `get_img()` being an `async def` endpoint, you could then execute the *synchronous* `create_img()` function in an external ThreadPool or PorcessPool so that the event loop does not get blocked. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), which provides details and examples on how to do that.

On a side note, if you are gettting the following warning when using `matplotlib`:

```
UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail.
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
```

this is because [`matplotlib` is not thread-safe](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq/howto_faq.html#work-with-threads), and most GUI backends require being run from the main thread (this is actually [a warning from Qt library itself](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13296#issuecomment-458361573)). To avoid getting that warning, you can simply cahnge to a non-GUI backend—since you don't even need one, as you are displaying the image in the user's browser on client side—using `matplotlib.use()`, as shown in the [Backends documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html) and in the example above (Note: `matplotlib.use()` must be used before importing `pyplot`). The `AGG` used in the example above is a backend that renders graphs as PNGs.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Chris works quite well (thank you!) but I found in my own work that adding an `async` can be important. Without an `async`, the buffers were being cut short when multiple requests were entering the FastAPI server. The solution was to allow asynchronous processing. Modifying Chris's answer:

```
import io
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('AGG')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, BackgroundTasks

app = FastAPI()

def create_img():
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [7.50, 3.50]
    plt.rcParams['figure.autolayout'] = True
    plt.plot([1, 2])
    img_buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(img_buf, format='png')
    plt.close()
    return img_buf
    
@app.get('/')
async def get_img(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    img_buf = create_img()
    # get the entire buffer content
    # because of the async, this will await the loading of all content
    bufContents: bytes = img_buf.getvalue()
    background_tasks.add_task(img_buf.close)
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="out.png"'}
    return Response(bufContents, headers=headers, media_type='image/png')
```