# How do I convert a torch tensor to an image to be returned by FastAPI?

Tags: python, pytorch, fastapi, starlette

I have a torch tensor which I need to convert to a byte object so that I can pass it to starlette's `StreamingResponse` which will return a reconstructed image from the byte object. I am trying to convert the tensor and return it like so:

```py
def some_unimportant_function(params):
    return_image = io.BytesIO()
    torch.save(some_img, return_image)
    return_image.seek(0)
    return_img = return_image.read()
    
    return StreamingResponse(content=return_img, media_type="image/jpeg")
```

The below works fine on regular byte objects and my API returns the reconstructed image:

```py
def some_unimportant_function(params):
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(some_image))

    return_image = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(return_image, "JPEG")
    return_image.seek(0)
    return StreamingResponse(content=return_image, media_type="image/jpeg")
```

Using `PIL` library for this

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What error/behavior are you getting?

Comment: ```TypeError: 'bytes' object is not an iterator``` and when I try turning it into an iterator I get ```AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'```

Comment: Why don't you convert the tensor into PIL Image object using [`torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage.html)?

Comment: It needs to be passed to the frontend as a byte object

Comment: Sure, you will just convert the tensor to PIL Image object then do what you have done in the PIL Image by saving it as byte object and sending it to the stream.

Comment: ahhh gotcha, Thanks! I also had to squeeze the tensor to get it into the correct shape as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting PyTorch Tensor to the PIL Image object using [torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage.html) module and then treating it as PIL Image as your second function would work. Here is an example.

```py
def some_unimportant_function(params):
    tensor = # read the tensor from disk or whatever
    image = torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()(tensor.unsqueeze(0))
    return_image = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(return_image, "JPEG")
    return_image.seek(0)
    return StreamingResponse(content=return_image, media_type="image/jpeg")
```

Comment: Using a `StreamingResponse`, while the image bytes are already fully loaded into memory, makes little sense. You should instead use a custom [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response), passing the image bytes and setting the `Content-Disposition` header, as described in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71643439/17865804) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804) answer.